# How can I generate a dropdown with Tailwind and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dropdown, tailwind-css

So I need to make a button where it can generate a new dropdown div and can be continued until it reaches the amount that the user desires.

One of the dropdown inputs data is appended to the JSON variable I created on the script. Thing is, I have a problem with making sure that the newly generated dropdown div has the same JSON data as well. It's gone whenever I generated a new dropdown. I would love to hear some advice for me to polishing on this part, or whether this method that I used is not doable and practical enough. Thank you.

I think this is the part where I make mistakes, to append based on looping the new generated dropdown.

```
<div class="mx-10 my-5 border border-black p-3 formDiv1 sm:rounded-lg">
                <h1 class="level">Level 1</h1>
                <div class="grid md:grid-cols-2 py-2">
                    <label for="approval_type_1" class="col-span-1 self-center py-2">Approval Type: <span
                            class="text-red-600">*</span></label>
                    <select name="approval_type_1" id="approval_type_1" class="col-span-2 w-full rounded py-2">
                        <option selected disabled>Please select approval type...</option>
                        <option value="1">In Consultation With</option>
                        <option value="2">Endorsed by</option>
                        <option value="3">Reviewed by</option>
                        <option value="4">Approved by</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="grid md:grid-cols-2 py-2">
                    <label for="approval_user_1" class="col-span-1 self-center py-2">Approval User: <span
                            class="text-red-600">*</span></label>
                    <select name="approval_user_1" id="approval_user_1" class="col-span-2 w-full rounded py-2 mySelect">
                        <option selected disabled>Please select a user...</option>
                    </select>
                </div>


const items = [
            {
                label: "Group Finance",
                value: "Group Finance"
            },
            {
                label: "Group Human Capital",
                value: "Group Human Capital"
            },
            {
                label: "Group Risk Management",
                value: "Group Risk Management"
            },
            {
                label: "Group Services and Communication",
                value: "Group Services and Communication",
            }
        ];

function appendOption(){
            var checkAppend = $(".mySelect").hasClass("addedList");
            $('.mySelect').addClass("addedList");
            $.each(items, function (i, item) {
                if(!checkAppend){
                    $('.mySelect').append($('<option>', { 
                        value: item.value,
                        text : item.label 
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
```

[CodePen Example of Mine](https://codepen.io/cleopatez/pen/YzEWvzR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery` is really useful, but there's a certain way it operates: when you use the `${selector}`, then it finds all items in the scope (usually `document`) that match the selector, and provides a list of items. **BUT if you start a chained operation right after the selector returns**, then the operator is applied to **the first element in the array**. `append()` is such an operator.

The other thing is that the elements you want the JSON appended to are `dynamic elements`: they are not there when the page loads, but are created dynamically. `dynamic elements` are not part of the simple `$(selector)` query - you have to dynamically "find" them after their creation.

So, the solution comes in two steps:

- you have to find the dynamically created elements
- you have to select the **last** element that matched your selector.

Here's a snippet that does both:

```js
const items = [{
    label: "Group 1",
    value: "Group 1"
  },
  {
    label: "Group 2",
    value: "Group 2"
  },
  {
    label: "Group 3",
    value: "Group 3"
  },
  {
    label: "Group 4",
    value: "Group 4",
  }
];

function appendOption() {

  /*
    $(document).find(selector) is dynamic: it refreshes on
    every run, so it finds the dynamically created elements.
    .last() is simply a jQuery function that gets you the
    last item from the matched set.
    
    $lastItem is a jQuery() object (that's why I put a $ as
    the first char in its name), so you can call jQuery
    functions on it, like .each()
  */
  const $lastItem = $(document).find('.mySelect').last()
  var checkAppend = $lastItem.hasClass("addedList");
  lastItem.addClass("addedList");

  $.each(items, function(i, item) {
    if (!checkAppend) {
      $lastItem.append($('<option>', {
        value: item.value,
        text: item.label
      }));
    }
  });
}

appendOption();

const getUserDataBtn = document.getElementById("get-user-data");
const getAddApprovalBtn = document.getElementById("addApproval");
const resetApprovalBtn = document.getElementById("resetApproval");

getUserDataBtn.addEventListener(
  "click",
  () => {
    console.log($("#approval_type").val());
  },
  false
);

getAddApprovalBtn.addEventListener(
  "click",
  () => {
    const levelsLoop = $(".level").length + 1;
    const fbRenderLength = ".formDiv" + levelsLoop;
    const fbRenderLength2 = ".formDiv" + (levelsLoop - 1);

    if (fbRenderLength == ".formDiv2") {
      $(".formDiv1").after(function() {
        return "<div class='mx-10 my-5 border border-black p-3 sm:rounded-lg formDiv" + levelsLoop + "'>" +
          "<h1 class='level'>Level " + levelsLoop + "</h1>" +
          "<div class='grid md:grid-cols-2 py-2'>" +
          "<label for='approval_type_" + levelsLoop + "' class='col-span-1 self-center py-2'>Approval Type: <span class='text-red-600'>*</span></label>" +
          "<select name='approval_type_" + levelsLoop + "' id='approval_type_" + levelsLoop + "' class='col-span-2 w-full rounded py-2'>" +
          "<option selected disabled>Please select approval type...</option>" +
          "<option value='1'>In Consultation With</option>" +
          "<option value='2'>Endorsed by</option>" +
          "<option value='3'>Reviewed by</option>" +
          "<option value='4'>Approved by</option>" +
          "</select>" +
          "</div>" +
          "<div class='grid md:grid-cols-2 py-2'>" +
          "<label for='approval_user_" + levelsLoop + "' class='col-span-1 self-center py-2'>Approval User: <span class='text-red-600'>*</span></label>" +
          "<select name='approval_user_" + levelsLoop + "' id='approval_user_" + levelsLoop + "' class='col-span-2 w-full rounded py-2 mySelect'>" +
          "<option selected disabled>Please select a user...</option>" +
          "</select>" +
          "</div>" +
          "</div>";
      });
    } else {
      $(fbRenderLength2).after(function() {
        return "<div class='mx-10 my-5 border border-black p-3 sm:rounded-lg formDiv" + levelsLoop + "'>" +
          "<h1 class='level'>Level " + levelsLoop + "</h1>" +
          "<div class='grid md:grid-cols-2 py-2'>" +
          "<label for='approval_type_" + levelsLoop + "' class='col-span-1 self-center py-2'>Approval Type: <span class='text-red-600'>*</span></label>" +
          "<select name='approval_type_" + levelsLoop + "' id='approval_type_" + levelsLoop + "' class='col-span-2 w-full rounded py-2'>" +
          "<option selected disabled>Please select approval type...</option>" +
          "<option value='1'>In Consultation With</option>" +
          "<option value='2'>Endorsed by</option>" +
          "<option value='3'>Reviewed by</option>" +
          "<option value='4'>Approved by</option>" +
          "</select>" +
          "</div>" +
          "<div class='grid md:grid-cols-2 py-2'>" +
          "<label for='approval_user_" + levelsLoop + "' class='col-span-1 self-center py-2'>Approval User: <span class='text-red-600'>*</span></label>" +
          "<select name='approval_user_" + levelsLoop + "' id='approval_user_" + levelsLoop + "' class='col-span-2 w-full rounded py-2 mySelect'>" +
          "<option selected disabled>Please select a user...</option>" +
          "</select>" +
          "</div>" +
          "</div>";
      });
    }
    appendOption();
  },
  false
);

resetApprovalBtn.addEventListener(
  "click",
  () => {
    $(".mainDiv").html("<div class='mx-10 my-5 border border-black p-3 formDiv1 sm:rounded-lg'>" +
      "<h1 class='level'>Level 1</h1>" +
      "<div class='grid md:grid-cols-2 py-2'>" +
      "<label for='approval_type_1' class='col-span-1 self-center py-2'>Approval Type: <span class='text-red-600'>*</span></label>" +
      "<select name='approval_type_1' id='approval_type_1' class='col-span-2 w-full rounded py-2'>" +
      "<option selected disabled>Please select approval type...</option>" +
      "<option value='1'>In Consultation With</option>" +
      "<option value='2'>Endorsed by</option>" +
      "<option value='3'>Reviewed by</option>" +
      "<option value='4'>Approved by</option>" +
      "</select>" +
      "</div>" +
      "<div class='grid md:grid-cols-2 py-2'>" +
      "<label for='approval_user_1' class='col-span-1 self-center py-2'>Approval User: <span class='text-red-600'>*</span></label>" +
      "<select name='approval_user_1' id='approval_user_1' class='col-span-2 w-full rounded py-2 mySelect'>" +
      "<option selected disabled>Please select a user...</option>" +
      "</select>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>");
    appendOption();
  },
  false
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8 pb-4">
  <div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="mx-10 my-5 border border-black p-3 formDiv1 sm:rounded-lg">
      <h1 class="level">Level 1</h1>
      <div class="grid md:grid-cols-2 py-2">
        <label for="approval_type_1" class="col-span-1 self-center py-2">Approval Type: <span
                            class="text-red-600">*</span></label>
        <select name="approval_type_1" id="approval_type_1" class="col-span-2 w-full rounded py-2">
          <option selected disabled>Please select approval type...</option>
          <option value="1">In Consultation With</option>
          <option value="2">Endorsed by</option>
          <option value="3">Reviewed by</option>
          <option value="4">Approved by</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="grid md:grid-cols-2 py-2">
        <label for="approval_user_1" class="col-span-1 self-center py-2">Approval User: <span
                            class="text-red-600">*</span></label>
        <select name="approval_user_1" id="approval_user_1" class="col-span-2 w-full rounded py-2 mySelect fromHTML">
          <option selected disabled>Please select a user...</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <label class="inline-flex items-center mt-3">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox h-5 w-5 text-gray-600" checked><span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">Add Concurrent Approver?</span>
            </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mx-10 my-5">
    <button class="h-12 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded m-2" type="button" id="addApproval">Add Approval</button>
    <button class="h-12 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded m-2" type="button" id="resetApproval">Reset Approval</button>
    <button class="h-12 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded m-2" type="button" id="get-user-data">Get Updated formData</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

IMPORTANT: doing such things with every click is not efficient. You should restructure your code so that the **last element is always available, you don't have to find it**. But I think this is another topic.

DISCLAIMER: I hope this answers your question, as I'm not 100% sure what you needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input, sir! I understand on what you're explaining about but unable to explain it to the question due to my lack of knowledge. I agree on restructuring this whole process, since I only made this as a prototype and not much thought put into it. Will start working on it, thanks again :)